# agregar descuento en la compra minima de 10 productos de una marca en específico woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Buenas como se puede agregar un descuento en el caso de que un cliente, compré 10 productos de la misma marca.

Cabe mencionar que son productos variables y también que tengo 2 marcas diferentes y otros productos "sueltos".

Que me recomendarían hacer en este caso, gracias de antemano.

Comment: tienes que hacerlo escribiendo codigo en php

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0):

podes engancharte al hook [`woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Cart.html#method_add_fee) y ahí contar los productos del cart o la cantidad de cada producto por marca, etc... con eso definis un fee ( temporal ) y lo agregas con [`$cart_object->add_fee( $descripcion, $cantidad, $taxable)`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Cart.html#method_add_fee)

```
add_action(
  'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees',
  'SOes559915_descuento_por_cantidad',
  10, 1
);

function SOes559915_descuento_por_cantidad( $cart_object ) {
  if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

  $descuento = false;

// contar los productos o los productos y sus cantidades 
// definir valor a $descuento

  if ($descuento) {
    $cart_object->add_fee( "Descuento:", -$descuento, false );
  }
}
```